# Putting hashes in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to generate this path tag based on the type in my view:

```
<%= nearby_#{@nearby_type}_shop_path %>
```

But the `#` sign commented out the rest of the text. Any solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `send` to actually execute the code.

```
<%= send("nearby_#{@nearby_type}_shop_path") %>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= "nearby_#{@nearby_type}_shop_path" %>
```

or

```
nearby_<%= @nearby_type %>_shop_path
```

Comment: I want to generate the path. Wrapping it with quotes results in normal text. I can't use the second.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-understood the question. I thought you were trying to print the full line. Didn't realize you were doing meta programming and trying to get the output of a method.